# how to reference an attribute before it exists python

Tags: python, oop, pygame, class-variables

I'm writing a game in pygame, and I have a class that makes a heads up display with stats for each building when you click on it.  the class variable current_hud starts as None, but when a building is clicked, its value becomes the building object so that when the draw function is called it only draws the hud of the selected building.

The problem is, I'm trying to create an instance of my "Text" class in the hud, but I'm getting the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' because self.current_hud isn't an object yet, so self.current_hud.name isn't an attribute yet.  How do I reference an attribute that doesn't exist yet?  is waiting to instantiate the hud class until after the building is clicked on really the only option?

```
 class Hud:
    current_hud = None
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name_text = Text(x,y,str(self.current_hud.name), (0,0,0), 36)

    def draw(self):
        if Hud.current_hud == self:
            self.square = pygame.Rect((self.x,self.y),(440,400))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),self.square)
            self.name_text.x = self.x + 10
            self.name_text.y = self.y + 20
```

sorry if this is convoluted, but it's a little difficult to explain.  The full code is here if you want to run it and see how it all works: https://github.com/hailfire006/economy_game/blob/master/economy_game.py

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Take another look at what you're intending to do, and try to think of a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Can you just set the current hud when you are doing the first instantiation?  (e.g. `if self.current_hud is None: self.current_hud = self`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the name as an option to the Hud class and set it prior to instantiating the Text class.

```
 class Hud:
    current_hud = None
    def __init__(self,x,y,name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.current_hud.name = name
        self.name_text = Text(x,y,str(self.current_hud.name), (0,0,0), 36)

    def draw(self):
        if Hud.current_hud == self:
            self.square = pygame.Rect((self.x,self.y),(440,400))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),self.square)
            self.name_text.x = self.x + 10
           self.name_text.y = self.y + 20
```

In your full code example it looks like when you instantiate a building you have its name and can then pass that along to the Hud on instantiation.

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self,posX,posY,color,name):
        self.hud = Hud(0,0,name)
```

Comment: this was what I needed, I'd never thought about passing it in as an instance variable but it seems obvious now...